# Defining XML animation to match programmatic definition

Tags: android, xml, animation, viewflipper

I am trying to replicate this Animation from code to XML form. This example is take from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/ViewFlipper_Animation.aspx. for example, I have the java code:

```
Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f, 
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, 
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, 
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
inFromRight.setDuration(350);
inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
```

To try and define this under my /res/anim/in_from_right.xml file, I tried something like the following but it didn't work.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schema.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" 
               android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="350"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Did you find how to construct Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT in xml ?

Comment: "p" in front of the value. i.e. 100%p